# React Hooks - refs for ScrollView in functional component with hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im converting a react native project from all class components to functional components with hooks. I have a messaging page with a ScrollView that auto scrolls to the bottom. How do i convert this to work in a functional component? Using ref and this.scrollView cause errors.

```
<ScrollView 
   ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
   onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=> {this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}}
>
{...content...}
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the body of your component:

```
function App(props) {    
   const scrollViewRef = useRef();
...
```

On the component:

```
<ScrollView 
   ref={scrollViewRef}
   onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=> {scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}}
>
{...content...}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this fixes the ref error, but i still have an error in the onContentSizeChange for using this.scrollView "undefined is not an object"

Comment: I would assume it would be `{scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd`

Answer (score 1):

const scrollRef = useRef(); in function App()

And in onPress use
scrollRef.current?.scrollTo({
y: 0,
animated: true,
});

Comment: If I want to move my scrollview to left side, what I should add. It works when scrollview needs to move on right side.